# Measuring Earth Radius using distance between two tall buildings

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Measuring Earth's radius using two tall building heights H and h with  a
ground separation s and also when the building tops are  collinear with the horizon:

Concluding result of concurrent thread " Heights and distances"...
After simplification I get the implicit relation from sketch given here from 
which R can be numerically evaluated:

$ cos(s/R) - sin(s/R) * \sqrt{( h ( 2 R +h) )}/R $  = $(R+h) /(R+H) $

[image: Earth Radius from local measurements]

But better still we can use much *simpler direct* implicit trigonometrical relation from two equations :

$cos(\alpha)= R/(R+h)$  and   $ cos( \alpha + s/R) = R/(R+H) $

For example H = 50 m, h = 49.6045  m, s =100 m, R ~ 6367.85 km. The buildings must be 
almost of equal height ( H or h << R ) to satisfy such horizon vision.

EDIT: Corrected earlier erroneous calculation ~ 6634 km

This is quite elementary trigonometry, but ( to me at least in the beginning) did not 
appear to be so, as now it is clear that implicit equation is unavoidable,

EDIT: But no problem as it can be exactly numerically calculated.

In an aviation situation, flying an aircraft towards a peak aligned with horizon ( most dangerous unless pitched up well before coming to peak h) ,flight height H versus ground distance s can be computed as R is known.

Comment: What about uncertainties?

Comment: What sketch? What is the question?

Comment: @metacompactness  what uncertainities?

Comment: @almagest  Please see "Heights and distances".

Comment: @Narasimham  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_uncertainty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Improved answer with minimal approximation]

Let the distance between the tops of the buildings be $L$, then with minuscule error,
$$
L = \sqrt{s^2 + (H-h)^2}
$$
If $R$ is the radius of the earth we have, for the taller building:
$$
R^2 + D^2 = (R+H)^2
$$
and for the shorter building:
$$
R^2 + (D-L)^2 = (R+h)^2
$$

Let
$$
V = 2R + h
$$
Then the two equations become
$$
D^2 = (V-h)H + H^2
\\ (D-L)^2 = hV
$$
and combining them by eliminating D leads to the following quadratic in $\sqrt{V}$:
$$
V(H-h) - 2L\sqrt{hV} + H^2 - hH - L^2 = 0
$$
which has positive solution
$$
\sqrt{V} = \frac{(L\sqrt{h} + s\sqrt{H})}{H-h}
$$
So finally
$$
R = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{(L\sqrt{h} + s\sqrt{H})^2}{(H-h)^2} - h \right)
$$
(and the term $-h$ can safely be neglected).

A nice practical illustration of this effect can be seen from the summit of Scafell Pike (978m), the highest mountain in England.  From that vantage point the neighbouring peak of Sca Fell, about 1km to the west, appears a little above the sea horizon, and might therefore be thought higher, though it’s actually only 964m. The formula above explains why (R = 6371km).

Comment: Quite interesting... i.e, on Sca Fell a prominent feature (like a tree or rock) was chosen for horizon alignment,both peak heights and intervening ground distances  measured accurately to get 6371km?

Comment: No, but I noticed the effect when I was up there a few years ago, which prompted me to do some sums along these lines, and you can check that the numbers work out about right from the figures I've given. The calculation won't give a precise value of R because refraction alters the apparent position of the horizon.

Comment: @MartinG.Please check R value calculated as above comes to 71,476.3 km, way above 6,634 km

Comment: With H = 50, h = 49.6045, s = 100 I get R = 6368 km.

Comment: Your result is correct and amazingly accurate 6367.75 km compared to the full trigonometric analytical formula result I gave above, which comes to 6367.85 km.   ( There was error in transferring data as  6634km, but else all is tallying OK)

Comment: Yes, the only error is a tiny one in the calculation of L, which is based on the assumption that the earth is flat between the two buildings.